# What is a Universal Word™?

Tags: word, wordplay

If a word conforms to a rule, I call it a Universal Word™. Can you figure out the pattern?

| Universal Words™ | Not Universal Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| acclaim | proclaim |
| lecture | talk |
| pajama | sleep |
| coupon | grocery |
| migratory | travel |
| ketchup | mustard |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Universal Word is one in which

> The A1Z26 sum of the letters is a multiple of 42, which is of course the answer to the great question of life, the universe and everything!

For example:

> ACCLAIM (A1Z26 sum) = 42
>  LECTURE (A1Z26 sum) = 84 (42 x 2)

Whereas:

> PROCLAIM (A1Z26 sum) = 87

BTW, interesting universal words include:

> LIBRA (a constellation), PLUTO, and TANIA BOREALIS (a star)